# Getting Error in middleware for the mobileesp While porting python2 project to python3

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm getting the error in the dependencies while porting python2 project with Django 1.1.11 to python 3.7 and Django 2.2.5.

I'm using Django-mobileesp in the python2, when I have updated the code to python3 it gives the error for the Middleware for the UserAgent.

> Exception in thread django-main-thread:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
>           self.run()
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
>           self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
>           fn(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
>           handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
>           handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
>           return get_internal_wsgi_application()
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
>           return import_string(app_path)
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
>           module = import_module(module_path)
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>         File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>         File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>         File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>         File "", line 728, in exec_module
>         File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/src/lawersify/wsgi.py", line 5, in 
>           application = get_wsgi_application()
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
>           return WSGIHandler()
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 135, in **init**
>           self.load_middleware()
>         File "/home/jarvis/Desktop/law3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 37, in load_middleware
>           mw_instance = middleware(handler)
>       TypeError: UserAgentDetectionMiddleware() takes no arguments

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE =  [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django_mobileesp.middleware.UserAgentDetectionMiddleware'
]


#middleware.py#

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject

DETECT_USER_AGENTS = getattr(settings, 'DETECT_USER_AGENTS', {})

def lazy_detection(request, key):
    detector = DETECT_USER_AGENTS[key]
    return SimpleLazyObject( lambda: detector(request) )


class UserAgentDetectionMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware to detect request's user agent
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        for each in DETECT_USER_AGENTS:
            setattr( request, each, lazy_detection(request, each) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Python version issue, but a Django one. The old (pre-Django 1.10) way of doing middleware, along with the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting, was removed in Django 2.0. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware) on how to make your middleware compatible with the new middleware structure.

Comment: Sir, I have changed the MIDDLEWARE accordingly but the issue is still there.